# How to give ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION in React Native app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, android-permissions

I need to give this permission ***ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION*** in react native.

Can anyone please tell me how I can put this permission in react native CLI APP?

Answer (score 1):

For ios, open ios file >>  <your_project_name> >> info.plist then add this:

```
<dict>
...
<key>UIDocumentBrowserViewController</key>
</dict>
```

For android, open the android file, then app >> src >> main >> AndroidManifest.xml then add this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

iOS reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller

android reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10467955?hl=en